# How to replace Pipelet for ExportCustomerGroups in SFCC? (For removing Deprecated API usage)

Tags: salesforce, demandware, salesforce-commerce-cloud

function abc(){

```
var Site = require('dw/system/Site');
var utils= require('app_nars/cartridge/scripts/util/utils.js');
var mySite : String = (Site.getCurrent().getID() == "a") ? "" : "-" + Site.getCurrent().getID();
var customerGroupName : String ; 
if (mySite == "A") {
    customerGroupName = "A";
} else { 

    customerGroupName = "B";
}
var grpNam= utils.getGroup(customerGroupName);
var grpFileName = 'test';
/* No script api available for pipelet ExportCustomerGroups*/
var Pipelet = require('dw/system/Pipelet');
var PipeletExecutionResponse = new dw.system.Pipelet('ExportCustomerGroups').execute({
    CustomerGroups: grpNam.iterator(),
    ExportFile  : grpFileName,
    OverwriteExportFile:true
});
app.getView().render('path/templateName');
```

}

How can we replace the Pipelet ExportCustomerGroups here , i could see in documentation we can use job steps and there is no script replacement

Answer (score 0):

You have to create with your own code, construct the xml needed while parsing the customers.[enter image description here][1]

Or you can use this step when configuring job if no custom code needed there:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1VQa.png